Achieve minimum memory use in Flutter Desktop App
I'm looking to build a Flutter Desktop App that can be run in background and while in the background I want to keep it memory consumption to a minimum.
When I run a simple Demo app "Counter Incrementor" built with "flutter build windows --release" it consumes 71.3 Mb of RAM (Windows 11). If I run the same app without creating any widget:
void main() {
  hold(); //keep app running.
  //runApp(const MyApp()); // DO NOT CREATE ANY WIDGET
}

It will consume 28.7 Mb. So I assume this is a bare minimum I can get out of Flutter App.
The idea I had was to destroy the widget while the app in the background. The way I do it is as suggested here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/runApp.html

To artificially cause the entire widget tree to be disposed, consider calling runApp with a widget such as SizedBox.shrink.

Unfortunatly this doesn't help at all (replaced action of the button to call a method below):
void releaseApp() {
  runApp(const SizedBox.shrink());
}

and the RAM usage jumped from 72.9 to 78 Mb. I did same test in debug mode and run GC after replacing main widget with SizedBox.shrink which didn't help either. When looking at widget inspector I see the widget is gone however memory consumption stays the same.
Played with other various ways. Nothing helps. Any ideas on how to minimize RAM usage and how to dispose Widgets properly so allocated memory is released?

why would you worry about 70MBs on a Desktop today?


I'm targeting old machines too. 2. As it is reasonable to expect that I believe - why would app that doesn't do almost anything consume 70Mb. I have similar app written for Windows only that consume 300 Kb RAM. 3. My app is not for Foreground mode (do stuff and close it). It will be sitting in the background always (performing small tasks) but will open when you press hot key.


At the very least I would like to know how to properly dispose of Widgets so the allocated memory is released.

I just checked with the default empty Flutter project running in release on Windows and it uses 28-33Mb how do you measure 70MBs? The Fluter windows runtime dll is about 17.5MB.
